# Polymorphic relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

When I started the project my RemitoEntry model had a common relationship with the Remito model and its migration is like this:

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('remito_entries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('remito_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('article_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('article_presentation_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('article_presentation_flat_name');
            $table->decimal('amount', 24, 2);
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('remito_entries');
    }
```

Then I had to adapt the model to accept a polymorphic relationship with the model 'Remito' and with the new model 'InternalRemito' and as I cannot modify the original migration I had to create a new one to modify it:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('remito_entries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('remito_id', 'remito_entriable_id');
            $table->string('remito_entriable_type')->default(Remito::class);
            $table->enum('type', ['internal', 'external']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('remito_entries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('remito_entriable_type');
            $table->renameColumn('remito_entriable_id', 'remito_id');
            $table->dropColumn('type');
        });
    }
```

My problem is that I can't create a RemitoEntry for an 'InternalRemito' model without first having created a RemitoEntry for the 'Remito' model, I don't understand why, I think that despite having changed the name, remito_entriable_id expects an id of the Remito model. How do I make remito_entriable_id to have an id of 'Remito' or 'InternalRemito'.

This is the error that postman shows me when I try to create a RemitoEntry for InternalRemito:

```
    "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`default`.`remito_entries`, CONSTRAINT `remito_entries_remito_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`remito_entriable_id`) REFERENCES `remitos` (`id`)) (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `remito_entries` (`type`, `article_id`, `article_presentation_id`, `article_presentation_flat_name`, `amount`, `remito_entriable_id`, `remito_entriable_type`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (internal, 1, 1, debitis, 1, 1, App\\Models\\InternalRemito, 1, 1, 2023-12-04 15:33:06, 2023-12-04 15:33:06))",
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us first examine what does `$table->foreignId('remito_id')->constrained();` do on the database:

1. Creates an unsigned big integer field of `remito_id`.
2. Creates a foreign key which references id on the remitos table.

Now let us dive into the polymorphic approach you want:

1. Polymorphic relations does not work on database level, like to one-to-one, one-to-many and so on.
2. Instead they work on Laravel level which means that the `remito_entriable_id` will not be defined to which table (relation) it belongs, it will only be guessed from the `remito_entriable_type` field.

Now the reason you get error is that you have an FK setup for `remito_entriable_id` which prevents entries. To fix your issue your migration should look like this:

```php
// Your new migration should like this

// execute this line if you haven't dropped the FK manually.
$table->dropForeign(['remito_id']);

$table->renameColumn('remito_id', 'remito_entriable_id');
$table->string('remito_entriable_type'); // We can't define the default on the migration as it can be any model, that is why it is called polymorphic
```

On your `RemitoEntry` model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

public function remitoEntriable(): MorphTo
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

On your `Remito` model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

 /**
  * Get all of the remito's entries.
  */
  public function remitoEntries(): MorphMany
  {
    return $this->morphMany(RemitoEntry::class, 'remitoEntriable');
  }
```

On your `InternationlRemito` model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

 /**
  * Get all of the internal remito's entries.
  */
  public function remitoEntries(): MorphMany
  {
    return $this->morphMany(RemitoEntry::class, 'remitoEntriable');
  }
```

You can also refactor this methods (which is same for all models) into a trait as:

```php
// HasRemitoEntries.php
namespace App\Traits\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use App\Models\RemitoEntry;

trait HasRemitoEntries
{
    /**
     * Get all of the remito's entries.
     */
    public function remitoEntries(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(RemitoEntry::class, 'remitoEntriable');
    }
}
```

And now you can use the trait in every model you want to polymorphed to `RemitoEntry` model.